# It's possible to change language without changing store view?

Tags: magento2, store-view, language, stores

I wonder if there is a way to setup a button to change the locale without having to change the store view, so this way you could create:

- Store 1
- Store 2
- Store 3

And change languages no matter in what store you are.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Chosen language is based on store ID.

Only option would be to translate outside of magento using an on screen translator.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

Unless you mean to have different websites. Then languages are set at store level.

Website 1 language 1 [store 1]

Website 1 language 2 [store 2]

Website 2 language 1 [store 3]

Website 2 language 2 [store 4]

That's possible